# Which Nvidia driver should i install for 5.3 Kernel

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Ubuntu 19.10

5.3.0-40-generic Kernel

Nvidia GeForce 920MX

Which driver should i install? as i know, 440 is not compatible..

Comment: 440 is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

440 is perfectly compatible.

I used `$ ubuntu-drivers devices` and 440 was recommended

Then `$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`